# jquery mobile won't mark radio checked

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I dynamically insert radio buttons from inside an API call function, the resulting buttons don't get marked as "checked" when you click on them, meaning they don't work correctly. They get the "ui-radio-on" class, but not the checked attribute, which means the .change() event doesn't fire either. Why?

```
// Show places list
user.getConnections("worksat", function(error, data, connections){  
for(var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
    var connection = connections[i];
    var place = connection.name;

    // Add place where person works at to list   
    $('#radio-clock-in').append('<label><input type="radio" name="clock-place" id="clock-' + place + '" value="' + place + '" />' + place + '</label>');
}

// refresh radio buttons
$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio();
});

//If I put the same .append() code right here, the button will behave normally
```

Also, the buttons style correctly, but don't acknowledge that they're inside a control group, so they're spread out instead of neatly packed.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="places">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="radio-clock-in">
    <!-- Dynamically injected radio buttons go here -->
</fieldset>
</div>
```

jquery mobile v1.4.0-rc1

*Update: Just wanted to note that if I put the exact same code outside of the user.getConnections function, the buttons work (attr gets checked) and the .change() event fires. I'm thinking it's something to do with the lag of the api call interfering.

Comment: Give `input` an id and `label` add `for=id_given` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update:

To attach event to radio buttons which are dynamically created:

```
$("static_parent").on("change", "dynamic_element", function () {
  // code
});
```

You can place it outside *user.getConnections* function.

---

To have checkbox / radio work correctly, you need to give each one a unique id, and add `for=id` to label tag.

```
<label for="unique_id"><input type="radio" name="clock-place" id="unique_id" value="" />Place</label>
```

Another note, elements should be appended to `.controlgroup("container")`.

```
$('#radio-clock-in').controlgroup("container").append(elements);
```

And then, *refresh* controlgroup.

```
$('#radio-clock-in').controlgroup("refresh");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ertz6/)**

Comment: I get the same results with this. Note that the same code placed outside of the user.getConnections function works fine.

Comment: also, as noted in the jqm docs, you don't need the "for" attribute if your input is nested in the label tag.

Comment: the perfect solution, awesome!

Comment: Omar, I couldn't find your contact info. I need to hire a jqm consultant for just an hour or 2, please contact me if interested at jlannen@gmail.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to move my event listener inside of the user.getConnections function:

```
$('[name=clock-place]').change(clockIn);
```

The control group not "grouping" is still pretty weird, although it works correctly if I create the radio list before this particular page shows.

Comment: it should work even if you place it outside your function and by using correct event binding to dynamic items `$("#radio-clock-in").on("change", "[name=clock-place]", function () { clockIn(); });`. The control group isn't _grouping_ because as of 1.4, you need to append them to controlgroup _container_ and then refresh it as I've mentioned in my answer below.